# What is the value of $(-1)^{\frac {2}{2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, exponentiation

When working with real numbers, should we interpret it as

$$\left( (-1)^{2} \right) ^{\frac 12}=1$$

or rather as

$$\left( (-1)^{{\frac 12}} \right) ^2= \text {not real/undefined}$$

or rather as $$(-1)^{\ 1} = -1$$

What about when we work with complex numbers?

**EDIT:**
The reason why I called the second case "undefined" is because when we are only working with reals, $(-1)^{\frac 12}$ is not real. I don't think we can assume that further algebraic manipulations that work on real numbers also work on our $(-1)^{\frac 12}$.

Comment: I think is it similar to $\sqrt{x^2} = \left|x\right|$, so applying the same idea, $x^{\frac{2}{2}}=\left|x\right|$, which implies 1 in this case.

Comment: To me $(-1)^{2/2}=-1$. Why you said that $i^2=-1$ is not real????

Comment: @Masacroso Well when only working with reals, $(-1)^{\frac 12}$ is not real, so I'm assuming we would just stop there and not assume that further algebraic manipulations that work on real numbers also work on our $(-1)^{\frac 12}$

Comment: In essence, you cannot extend the rules of exponents blindly to negative bases. There are plenty of numerical examples to show that

Comment: @Ovi That is like Casus irreducibilis, just because we run into complex numbers doesn't mean they won't all cancel out in the end.  Which is exactly what can happen, and if we don't allow ourselves to "sneak" in with complex numbers, well, we run into a brick wall... and that's not very productive usually.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on what the person who wrote down $(-1)^{\frac22}$ *meant* by writing that.

The notation $A^B$ has a well-defined meaning that everybody agree on in the following cases

- $B$ is a natural number.
- $B$ is a (possibly negative) integer, and $A\ne 0$.
- $B$ is real and $A$ is positive.
- $A$ is $e$, and $B$ is any complex number.

The definitions of exponentiation that work in each of these cases are different, but fortunately they *agree about the result* whenever some combination of $A$ and $B$ fits into more than one of them.

Outside of these cases, ambiguity creeps in. In the general case of complex $A$ and $B$, one can treat $A^B$ as a *multi-valued* expression, but in some contexts it can be useful to single out a single one of the multiple values as the one we mean. (Indeed this is what happens in the two last of the cases above, where the canonical meaning of $A^B$ is only one of the multiple values the general case allows).

In particular, the rule that $A^{BC} = (A^B)^C$ holds in the three first cases cases, but **not necessarily** for a wider generalization that one might wish to use in a particular case.

For your particular case $(-1)^{\frac 22}$ does not *immediately* fall into any of the above categories. If we observe that $\frac22=1$, then we can rewrite it to $(-1)^1$ which does match the first two cases and gives the result $-1$.

However, the fact that somebody wrote the expression as $(-1)^{\frac22}$ suggests that they may have meant something different from that, and then there's no way out of either *asking them*, or try to figure out for yourself which interpretation of the notation makes sense in the context you see it in.

Comment: I didn't see $(-1)^{\frac 22}$ anywhere, I was just wondering about it, and I tried asking myself what I meant but I didn't know :)

Comment: @Ovi: Ah -- in that case the answer is that it doesn't mean anything that people will agree on. :-) In a particular situations it may be convenient to _let it_ mean something, but the onus is then on the writer to be really clear about which meaning he chooses for it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm They might have meant something different but since 2/2=1 the answer must be -1 regardless of intent.

Answer (score 1):

The rule
$$a^{m/n} = (a^m)^{1/n} = (a^{1/n})^m$$
typically comes with the restriction that $a \ge 0$ if $n$ is even, so that rule can't really be applied to $(-1)^{2/2}$.  I think the right way would be to simplify the exponent as much as possible first, then evaluate:
$$(-1)^{2/2} = (-1)^1 = -1$$

The question about complex numbers is a little vague in its current form.  By "work with complex numbers" do you mean what if we allow complex numbers so that $(-1)^{1/2} = i$ and isn't considered undefined?  Do you mean what do we do if the base is complex and non-real?  The exponent?

Comment: Yes, if we allow complex numbers, then the case of $\left( (-1)^{{\frac 12}} \right) ^2$ would equal $-1$ as well, and since it matches with your answer above I think $-1$ is the right interpretation to chose.